# Angular Material - Pre-rendered dialog doesn't appear but the background color changes

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, angular-material

I'm trying to create a pre-rendered modal using angular-material. When I click the button that should fire the modal, the screen becomes dark gray (the modal background) as if the modal is there but the actual modal doesn't appear. I have basically copied it straight from Angular Material's demo so I am not sure why it isn't working.

**HTML**

```
<md-button class="md-raised md-primary"ng-click="vm.showModal($event)">
     Add Review
</md-button>
<md-dialog layout-padding aria-label="myDialog" id="myDialog" class="dialog">
    <md-dialog-content>
        <h2>Pre-Rendered Dialog</h2>
        <p>
            This is a pre-rendered dialog, which means that <code>$mdDialog</code> doesn't compile its
            template on each opening.
            <br/><br/>
            The Dialog Element is a static element in the DOM, which is just visually hidden.<br/>
            Once the dialog opens, we just fetch the element from the DOM into our dialog and upon close
            we restore the element back into its old DOM position.
        </p>
    </md-dialog-content>
</md-dialog>
```

**CSS**

```
.dialog {
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

**Controller**

```
function showModal(ev) {
      $mdDialog.show({
        contentElement: '#myDialog',
        parent: angular.element(document.body),
        targetEvent: ev,
        clickOutsideToClose: true
      });
}
```

Comment: I went ahead and copied exactly from Angular Material's demo page and still have the same behavior, so I must have done something wrong in my configuration.